Can't Auto Fill Form When Trying To Edit - CRUD
Hello I was trying to use the Edit function from Laravel CRUD with resource. The problem that I got is that the form is not filling any of the old data that I already created using the value="{{ old('kodecust', $customer->kodecust ) }}"````` or  `````value="{{ $customer->kodecust ) }}". The other function like Read,Delete, and Create are working except the Update/Edit.
Here is my Route:
Route::resource('/customer/mastercustomer', CustomerController::class)->except(['destroy'])->middleware("auth");
Route::delete('/customer/mastercustomer/{customer:perusahaancust}', [CustomerController::class, 'destroy'])->middleware('auth');

My Controller:
public function edit(Customer $customer)
    {

        return view('Master\Customer\editcustomer', [
            "customer" => $customer,
            "title" => "Edit Customer"
        ]);
    }

public function update(Request $request, Customer $customer)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'kodecust' => 'required|string|max:15',
            'perusahaancust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'kontakcust' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'kotacust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'alamatcust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'alamat2cust' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'notelponcust' => 'required|string|max:30',
            'termcust' => 'required|integer',
            'limitcust' => 'required',
            'desccust' => 'nullable|string|max:50',
        ]);

        Customer::where('perusahaancust', $customer->perusahaancust)
                ->update($validatedData);

        return redirect('/customer/mastercustomer')->with('success', 'Berhasil Edit Customer!');
    }

And My View:
<tr>
                            <td><label for="kodecust">Kode</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="kodecust" id="kodecust" value="{{ old('kodecust', $customer->kodecust ) }}" required style="width: 50px"
                                    @error('kodecust') class="is-invalid" @enderror>
                                @error('kodecust')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </td>
                            <td><label for="perusahaancust">Perusahaan</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="perusahaancust" id="perusahaancust" value="{{ old('perusahaancust', $customer->perusahaancust) }}" required
                                    style="width: 200px" @error('perusahaancust') class="is-invalid" @enderror>
                                @error('perusahaancust')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><label for="kontakcust">Kontak</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="kontakcust" id="kontakcust" value="{{ old('kontakcust', $customer->kontakcust) }}" required style="width: 100px"
                                    @error('kontakcust') class="is-invalid" @enderror>
                                @error('kontakcust')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </td>
                            <td><label for="kotacust">Kota</label></td>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="kotacust" id="kotacust" value="{{ old('kotacust', $customer->kotacust) }}" required style="width: 150px"
                                    @error('kotacust') class="is-invalid" @enderror>
                                @error('kotacust')
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">{{ $message }}</div>
                                @enderror
                            </td>
                        </tr>

Let me know if you guys wanted to see more of my code. I will appreciate any help, thankyou!
Using dd($customer); result ini:
App\Models\Customer {#1407 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\CustomerController.php:73
  #connection: null
  #table: "customers"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  +preventsLazyLoading: false
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #attributeCastCache: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  +usesUniqueIds: false
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "id"
  ]
}


Is it blank or are you getting any error while form is not getting filled?
Are sure you have imported correct model to the top of the controller use App\Model\Customer?
which version of laravel you are using ?

@Subha there's no error given, its just blank and i use Laravel 11. Yes i already have the use App\Models\Customer; on my customercontroller

You mean edit form is loaded but the form field is blank.Right?
Are you sure that $customer returning data? If there is no matching Id then $customer will return null by default.

@Subha it does return data cause i use the read function and it works perfectly. is it any different than that?

Have you tried this dd($customer)  inside edit(... method to check if it returns expected data.

yes unfortunately using dd result in no data whatsoever, I've update the dd result in my question

Just confirm me that are you sure that you fetching result against a valid id?

@Subha yes im sure

Okay last thing.Which column of Customer model is mapped by the $customer?Is it id or any other column ?Please specify.

its the perusahaancust

I have posted my answer. Please check & let me know about the result.Thanks

I think there is some issue with implicit-model-binding with Resource- Controller.Because model-binding fetch record by id which in your case is not. So dont use implicit-model-binding untill you know what the actual issue is. Instead you try this.
public function edit($customer)
{

        $results = Customer::where('perusahaancust', $customer)->first();

        return view('Master\Customer\editcustomer', [
            "customer" => $results,
            "title" => "Edit Customer"
        ]);
}

Before using the above code please make sure the following notes.

Your Customer model class has protected $table = 'table-name-in DB'.
Sometime naming convention also causes error.
Try dd($customer) to see that it returns a single value upon which
DB record will be fetched.

If above mentioned two condition is met,I hope the code will work.
If not the please let me know.
For update(...) method do this.
public function update(Request $request, $customer)
    {
        $results = Customer::where('perusahaancust', $customer)->first();
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'kodecust' => 'required|string|max:15',
            'perusahaancust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'kontakcust' => 'required|string|max:100',
            'kotacust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'alamatcust' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'alamat2cust' => 'nullable|string|max:255',
            'notelponcust' => 'required|string|max:30',
            'termcust' => 'required|integer',
            'limitcust' => 'required',
            'desccust' => 'nullable|string|max:50',
        ]);

        Customer::where('perusahaancust', $results->perusahaancust)
                ->update($validatedData);

        return redirect('/customer/mastercustomer')->with('success', 'Berhasil Edit Customer!');
    }

Don't use implicit model-binding .I have also mentioned this before.
Try this.I hope it will work.

You're right and now its working thankyou so much, but if you don't mind i have another problem. first it show "The PUT method is not supported for route customer/mastercustomer. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST." error and I've fixed it by adding $customer->perusahaancust in the form Action. but now when I edit any of the value, its not changing anything

If it's working then please upvote.What you are editing?An what valu is not changing?
Can you please explain.
have you used this $customer->perusahaancust in edit form ?

@NyK Can you please share the <form> tag where you used $customer->perusahaancust ?Please mention is it edit form?

i was just testing if i can edit any information on the customer, but nothing changes. i've updated my  question to include the public function update on the controller

@NyK, I have updated my answer for public function update . Please check and let me know.And please accept answer & upvote if it works.

i have accepted your answer even though i have another problem. Somehow now every value has an error "Attempt to read property on null". i didnt change anything from yesterday

@Nyk are you getting error for the update function? Did you try the above code for update() that i mentioned in the answer by editing it??please try and let me know

@NyK, Can you please show me the code block about how you pass id for update() and it's route defination? And please specify when and in which line you are getting the erro that you mentioned.

@NyK i have changed the update() exactly like your answer, My route definition is still the same as in my question above
And the error line is on every value like value="{{ old('kodecust', $customer->kodecust ) }}", and when i give  ?? '' it has another error in value="{{ old('perusahaancust', $customer->perusahaancust ) }}"and so on

@NyK, That means update() funtion is not working.Right? does perusahaancust column has unique value in each record? if update() function is not working then please do dd($results) after $results=.. to check it returns expected result.Let me know what you got.

dd($results) came back with a null. And the perusahaancust doesnt have a unique value

that is the reason it is not working..is it all inside update()  I mean to say have you performed dd($results) inside update() method?

iam deeply sorry if i got you confuse, but i think the problem is now back to the edit function because i got Attempt to read property on null after i press the edit button. i tried dd($customer); it return a result like in my question above (i've updated it) and dd($results) gave me a null

@NyK, Okay..let me summarize all the points..

At first you should pass unique-field for edit and update.please pass id instead of  perusahaancust .
2)Carefully check how did you pass field through action of the form?
I have another confusion that at first you told me that its working then why currently its not working..
I am 100% sure that there is something wrong with the field(i.e. perusahaancust.id ).If this field is not passed properly code will not work.
please let me know your view after going through all the points i mentioned.


@NyK, If you want I will create a chat and will solve your problem..
I need to see your form,Controller and route.

yeah sure i got no problem with that
